# Why don't I get a runtime exception for key duplication?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

In a `HashMap` named `map` I duplicate the `keys` but I still do not get any run time exception of key duplication. Why is it so ?

The map data structure cannot have duplicate keys.

```
import java.util.*;

class KeyTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("key-1","val");
        map.put("key-1","val");
        map.put("key-1","val");
        map.put("key-1","val");
        map.put("key-1","val");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it throw an exception?  Why would you want it to? What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't get any `exception`.It just overrides the existing `value` with that `key`.

And it is mentiond in the docs of [HashMap#Put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

```
 map.put("key-1","val1");
 map.put("key-1","val2");
```

In that case  the current `value` for the `key` `key-1` is `"val2"` ,because `"val1"` is replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to [Map#put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.
>
> Returns:
> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

Answer (score 1):

`Map.put` does not throw exception on duplicate key. You can test the return value of put, if it is not `null` then the key is duplicate. If it's `null` then it depends on whether a concrete map implementation allows nulls or not. `HashMap` does.